# Link gdb args with argc/argv

Tags: gdb, args

I have a program that takes many complex command line arguments that are generated via front end bash scripts.  To debug, I generally call gdb with a hand entered set of these using the 'set args' command.

What I'd like to do is run my target code on another server with gdbserver and its args there using the bash script front ends that generate the args, then connect to it with gdb and 'pick up' the args that were passed in with gdbserver on the target machine.  Essentially, linking "set args" with whatever argc/argv[] are in use when main() is hit.  This would allow me to re-run the target without losing the argument list and having to enter it manually using "set args" (Painful...).

Is this even possible?  Can gdb's args be automatically linked to the program's args and if so, can it be done through a gdbserver connection?

Thanks,

XL600

Comment: I can brute force this effect in my .gdbinit file along the lines of    

if argc==2
        eval "set args %s", argv[1]
end

But that seems silly given the number of args my program can handle is greater than 20.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like to do is run my target code on another server with gdbserver and its args there using the bash script front ends that generate the args,

I am not sure I understand the difficulty. You could do:

```
gdbserver :1234 a.out $(generate_args.sh)
```

or

```
gdb --args a.out $(generate_args.sh)
```

Comment: I’d like to get both effects at the same time.  Pass in args via gbdserver (argc and argv) and have gdb’s args set to the same thing automatically so I can rerun the app from the gdb side using the run command.